# поиск по связанным полям yii2

Tags: yii2

связанные поля я вывел: http://joxi.ru/a2XOvoWi197WPm
но если пробовать поиск по ним, то получаю ошибку вида: http://joxi.ru/xAe5VWYipvZ4WA

модель - DishSearch.php:

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\Dish;

/**
 * DishSearch represents the model behind the search form about `common\models\Dish`.
 */
class DishSearch extends Dish
{
    /* вычисляемый атрибут */
    public $categoryNameRu;
    public $categoryNameEn;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'weight', 'category_id', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['title_ru', 'title_en', 'desc_ru', 'desc_en', 'url', 'img_url', 'categoryNameRu', 'categoryNameEn'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Dish::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
          $query->joinWith(['category']);
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $this->addCondition($query, 'title_ru');
        $this->addCondition($query, 'title_en');

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'weight' => $this->weight,
            'category_id' => $this->category_id,
            'status' => $this->status,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title_ru', $this->title_ru])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title_en', $this->title_en])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'desc_ru', $this->desc_ru])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'desc_en', $this->desc_en])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'url', $this->url])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'img_url', $this->img_url]);

        $query->joinWith(['category' => function ($q) {
            //$q->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tbl_category.title_ru', $this->categoryNameRu]);
          //$q->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tbl_category.title_en', $this->categoryNameEn]);
          $q->where('tbl_category.title_ru LIKE "%' . $this->categoryNameRu . '%"');
          $q->where('tbl_category.title_ru LIKE "%' . $this->categoryNameEn . '%"');
        }]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

модель Dish.php

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "dish".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $title_ru
 * @property string $title_en
 * @property string $desc_ru
 * @property string $desc_en
 * @property string $url
 * @property string $img_url
 * @property integer $weight
 * @property integer $category_id
 * @property integer $status
 *
 * @property Category $category
 */
class Dish extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'dish';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title_ru', 'title_en', 'category_id'], 'required'],
            [['weight', 'category_id', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['weight'], 'integer', 'max' => 300, 'min' => -300],
            [['title_ru', 'title_en', 'desc_ru', 'desc_en', 'url', 'img_url'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['category_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Category::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['category_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title_ru' => 'Title Ru',
            'title_en' => 'Title En',
            'desc_ru' => 'Desc Ru',
            'desc_en' => 'Desc En',
            'url' => 'Url',
            'img_url' => 'Img Url',
            'weight' => 'Weight',
            'category_id' => 'Category ID',
            'categoryNameRu' => 'Category Name (RU)',
            'categoryNameEn' => 'Category Name (EN)',
            'status' => 'Status',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    /* Связь с моделью Category*/
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
    }

    /* Геттер для названия категории */
    public function getCategoryNameRu() {
        return $this->category->title_ru;
    }

    /* Геттер для названия категории */
    public function getCategoryNameEn() {
        return $this->category->title_en;
    }
}
```

не могу понять почему поиск не работает, вроде сами поля выводятся и значения правильные самих категорий

Answer (score 0):

Ругается ведь на метод `addCondition` значит не используйте его. Попробуйте сделать поиск в `DishSearch.php` через `andFilterWhere` как там ниже.